# how to access base class attribute from child objects in python

Tags: python

I am used to writing in C++, and I am getting attribute error. Basically I have a parent attribute accessed via a child class and using child class objects.

```
class temp ():
    def __init__(self):
        self.t1 = 500
        self.t2 ="temp testing"

class parent ():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a1 = ""
        self.a2 = 0
        self.alist = []

class child (parent):
    def __init__(self):
        parent.__init__(self)
        ## i want to define is C++ , initalizing values
        a1 = "fun1"
        a2 = 200
        t1 = temp()
        t1.t1 = 100
        t1.t2 = "modified testing"
        alist.append(t1)

    def dis_name(self):
        print a1

gchild = child()
gchild.a1 = "modified child"
gchild.dis_name()
```

Comment: You still have to have reference the child object as `self` when defining attributes.  I.e. `self.a1` in the child class

Answer (score 1):

You are missing several `self` references in your child object.

```
class temp ():
    def __init__(self):
        self.t1 = 500
        self.t2 ="temp testing"

class parent ():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a1 = ""
        self.a2 = 0
        self.alist = []

class child (parent):
    def __init__(self):
        parent.__init__(self)
        self.a1 = "fun1"
        self.a2 = 200
        t1 = temp()
        t1.t1 = 100
        t1.t2 = "modified testing"
        self.alist.append(t1)

    def dis_name(self):
        print(self.a1)

gchild = child()
gchild.a1 = "modified child"
gchild.dis_name()
```